# Why does Hello World for V8 cause a segmentation fault on Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, compiler-construction, segmentation-fault, v8

I have compiled [V8](https://code.google.com/p/v8/) on Ubuntu 14.04 and am now trying to get the sample [hello_world.cc](https://developers.google.com/v8/get_started) working, however, when I execute it I get a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

Here's my source for hello_world.cc:

```
#include <v8.h>

using namespace v8;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  // Get the default Isolate created at startup.
  Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();

  // Create a stack-allocated handle scope.
  HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);

  return 0;
}
```

Following the instructions, here's the command I used to build hello_world.cc into an executable:

```
g++ -Iinclude -g hello_world.cc -o hello_world -Wl,--start-group out/x64.debug/obj.target/{tools/gyp/libv8_{base,snapshot},third_party/icu/libicu{uc,i18n,data}}.a -Wl,--end-group -lrt -lpthread
```

Note that, in addition to the instructions, I had to add `-lpthread` flag to get it to compile and `-g` to include the debug symbols.

Here's the output from the program:

```
$ ./hello_world
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

And if I run `gdb hello_world core` I get:

```
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `./hello_world'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00000000004148bb in v8::HandleScope::Initialize (this=0x7fff9b86a110, isolate=0x0) at ../src/api.cc:572
572   prev_next_ = current->next;
```

Line 572 from [src/api.cc is here](https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/api.cc#572)

Comment: Have you tried running the *whole* example as opposed to just the first quarter?

Comment: Yes, it segfaults at the same line. I removed everything after it to avoid posting code which wasn't relevant to the problem.

Comment: the gdb trace tells you what is wrong, isolate is a null pointer, so current will probably be a garbage address as well, look into Isolate::GetCurrent to see why you get a null pointer

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely the cause, though a solution still eludes me. I've asked a new question about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23825034/in-v8-why-does-isolategetcurrent-return-null

Comment: I ran into this issue earlier today when using a snapshot `snapshot_blob.bin` from a previous v8 installation, it is possible the snapshot was corrupted or another less obvious issue, but it's a clue for anyone else running into this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Add a check for `Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();` returning `NULL`:

```
Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
if(!isolate) {
    isolate = v8::Isolate::New();
    isolate->Enter();
}
```